# Re-upload file to GitHub, with no change? Does this even make sense?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to re-upload a file to GitHub without changing it? The file is a .zip, and I'm wondering if it was a corrupted file; then again, if there isn't a diff, then maybe it's exactly the same.

1) Is there a way to re-upload a file, even if you haven't changed it (I.e., no changes to push).

2) In the scenario I described, does it even make sense to try?

Comment: Was it moved around? renamed?

Comment: @ntg Nope. In a way, that's part of what I want to avoid ... I don't want to make false changes to the file and commit those changes just so I can get the file to upload again (lfs isn't implemented on this repo, and I don't want to take up the extra space if I don't have to; this .zip is somewhat large)

Comment: If you committed something, then it is guaranteed to arrive at GitHub identically.  This is guaranteed by the SHA1 hash.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty OK, that's kind of what I was wondering. So if there is a difference between what I uploaded and what I downloaded from GitHub, then it means that the download was messed up, but the copy on the site is identical to what I originally put there. Correct?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about things *committed* to Git (as opposed to GitHub's Downloads section, which isn't Git), then yes.  Git preserves the integrity of everything you commit.  So it could be the download that is messed up.

Comment: Well, that's not *strictly* true; Git does munge line endings on text files.  But binary files (such as zip archives) are preserved exactly as you commit them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to re-upload a file, even if you haven't changed it (I.e., no changes to push).

I guess you could make a clone of the repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:you/yourrepo.git copy-of-myrepo
```

And then roll it back to a commit that doesn't have that file:

```
cd copy-of-myrepo
git reset --hard 12345
```

And then force push it:

```
git push -f origin master
```

And then go back to your original working copy and push it:

```
cd /path/to/myrepo
git push origin master
```

> In the scenario I described, does it even make sense to try?

Probably not, no.

You could always verify the integrity of the zip file by downloading it and comparing a checksum on the downloaded copy against a checksum of the original archive.  E.g.,

```
sha1sum myfile.zip
```